# Django 3.2.11 LTS admin change form and change list page shows all the models

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-3.2

I am using django version 3.2.11, and on change form, change list page of every model it shows all the models.
I have attached the image.
PS: collectstatic command is run too. and no admin template customization is done.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer:
Just set this in root urls.py

```
admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```